# Infrared touch frame with Android TV not working! android.hardware.touchscreen?

Tags: touchscreen, android-11, android-tv, multi-touch

I recently purchased a 55" Infrared touch frame for my Android TV 55", this IR frame works perfectly when I connect it to a PC with Windows 10 via USB no drivers are needed.

However, when I connect the same frame to my TV OS:Android TV 11, there's no response to touch input.

After some research, I came across the concept of "android.hardware.touchscreen" in Android and started wondering if this feature might be disabled on Android TV OS, preventing the IR frame from functioning. My questions are:

- **Is it possible that a disabled "hardware.touchscreen" feature is causing my issue?** I haven't found any definitive information about whether Android TVs generally have this feature enabled or disabled by default.
- If so, **is there a way to enable "hardware.touchscreen" on my Android TV?** I'm hesitant to tinker with settings even if it could potentially harm my TV.
- **Are there any other potential causes for the IR frame not working on my Android TV?** It would be helpful to understand other areas I could investigate.

Comment: When you have connected it to Windows as what USB device type is it detected (see device manager)?

Comment: AFAIK, `android.hardware.touchscreen` indicates [if an Android device has a built-in touchscreen or not](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/11/android-11-cdd#7_2_4_touchscreen_input), e.g. for hardware filtering in the Play Store. However, I don't know if it affects support for external touchscreen devices. Do you have an Android phone/tablet to test the IR frame? On the other hand, I wonder if the Android kernel driver supports such a device.

Comment: @AndrewT. I will check and revert tomorrow using an OTG cable with a phone. otherwise if the issue is kernel related, does this need an additional implementation of the driver ?

Comment: @Robert : Yes it is detected in device manager and working with Windows PC

Comment: If you can use it in Windows then it is obvious that you can find it in device manager, what I was asking for is as what device type it is found. So what driver is used and what USB properties does the device has?

Comment: @Robert I will check tomorrow and revert back to you! thanks!